# Proof of Theorem 1.4.1 in Ratcliffe book Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds

Tags: euclidean-geometry, manifolds, geodesic

I’m reading Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds by John G. Ratcliffe (third edition). In his proof of Theorem 1.4.1, he demonstrates that any two points on a Euclidean geodesic through the origin are given by linearly dependent vectors $ \beta(s) $ and $ \beta(l) $ where $ s \in [0, l] $. He shows linear dependence after making the claim for a geodesic arc $\beta$ where $\beta(0)=0$ that $|\beta(s)|=s$.

My confusion comes from this last statement. If $|\beta(s)|=s$, then it appears he is assuming geodesics in Euclidean space are straight lines. (This comes from his definition of geodesic lines as distance preserving maps $\beta : [0, l] \rightarrow R$ so that the length of the geodesic curve between $0$ and $\beta(s)$ is $s$. Thus the statement $|\beta(s)|=s$ says the length of the curve, $s$, is the same as the length of the vector $\beta(s)$, so the geodesic curve is a straight line). One might argue this is a well known fact, but it appears that this is what he is actually trying to prove. That is to say, he concludes (mid way through the proof) that $ \beta(s) $ and $ \beta(l) $ are linearly dependent, and thus all points on a Euclidean geodesic lie on a straight line. But in order to prove this, he appears to be making that assumption in the first place when stating $ |\beta(s)|=s $.

Can anyone see where I’m getting this wrong?

Included below is the full stated theorem and proof as stated in the book:

[image]

The proof references theorem 1.3.1 (Cauchy’s Inequality)
[image]

Comment: Please edit your post to state, explicitly, the full statement whose proof you are asking about. This should include a careful explanation of the meaning of the $\beta$ notation, the conclusions regarding that notation, etc. Without that, it's very difficult to know what you are asking.

Comment: Excellent point, thank you. I have edited my post to include the full statement of theorem and its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the proof you are reading is the proof of the implication (1)$\implies$(2), and the proof starts, naturally enough, by assuming that $\alpha : [a,b] \to \mathbb E^n$ is a geodesic. By definition of a geodesic, it follows that the distance from $\alpha(a)$ to $\alpha(a+s)$, namely the quantity $| \alpha(a) - \alpha(a+s) |$, is equal to $s$ (for all $s \in [0,l] = [0,b-a]$).

Now they define a new function $\beta(s) = \alpha(a+s)-x$. It follows that
\begin{align*}
|\beta(s)| &= |\beta(s)-0| \\ &= |\beta(s)-\beta(0)| \\ &= |(\alpha(a+s)-x) - (\alpha(a+0)-x)| \\&= |\alpha(a+s)-\alpha(a)| \\& = s
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your response! I’m not sure this resolves my query. Saying $|\alpha(a+s) - \alpha(a)| = s$, is to say that the length, $s$, of the geodesic is the length of the vector $\alpha(a+s) - \alpha(a)$. i.e. the geodesic between these two points is a straight line. Likewise we are saying the geodesic between $0$ and $\beta(s)$ is a straight line $\forall s \in [0, l]$. But the conclusion after applying Cauchy’s inequality is exactly this! I.e. $0$, $\beta(s)$ and $\beta(l)$ lie on a straight line. So we are assuming what we are trying to prove with Cauchy’s inequality. This can’t be right.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more clearly: You wanted to know why the equation $|\beta(s)|=s$ is true, correct? If so, my explanation shows how it follows from the hypotheses given. But perhaps I misread your post and failed to understand what you actually wanted to know?

Comment: Hey, so what I am saying is the conclusion drawn after applying Cauchy’s inequality is that the points $0, \beta(s)$ and $\beta(l)$ lie on a straight line. Which I believe is to conclude that Euclidean geodesics are straight lines. However, this is conclusion is reached only after stating $|\beta(s)|=s$, which is only possible if Euclidean geodesics are straight lines. So he is using that fact that Euclidean geodesics are straight lines to prove that Euclidean geodesics are straight lines! So my point is this can’t be right, or I am missing the point somewhere.

Comment: Let me highlight a logical point. I have given a proof of the implication (1) $\implies$ $|\beta(s)|=s$. Do you now agree that the implication (1) $\implies$ $|\beta(s)|=s$ is a true implication? And if so, do you agree that in proving the implication (1) $\implies$ (2), we may now use the fact that the equation $|\beta(s)|=s$ is true?

Comment: By the way, let me emphasize that contrary to what you wrote in your post and repeated in your comment, the proof of the implication (1)$\implies|\beta(s)|=s$ does not depend on any assumption that "geodesics in Euclidean space are straight lines" or any other foggy, intuitive notion. It is, instead, a straight-up mathematical deduction, depending only on what is stated in (1).

Comment: Thanks again for your very helpful response! I think my issue lies in the claim (1) $ \implies |\beta(s)|=s$ being a true implication, as you ask above. In the proof which you shared, I’m struggling with the last step; $|\alpha(a+s)-\alpha(a)|=s$. I think you say this because given $\alpha$ is a geodesic, which is a distance preserving map, then its length between points $\alpha(a+s)$ and $\alpha(a)$ is $s$. I agree with that. But if we don’t assume $\alpha$  is a straight line, then the length of this curve is given by $\int_{a}^{a+s} |\alpha’(t)| dt$, and not $|\alpha(a+s)-\alpha(a)|$.

Comment: The *very definition* of a geodesic tells us that for all $x,y$ in the domain of $\alpha$, the length of the restriction of $\alpha$ to the interval $[x,y]$ is equal to the distance in the plane between the two points $\alpha(x)$ and $\alpha(y)$, which by the distance formula is equal to $|\alpha(x)-\alpha(y)|$.

Comment: By distance in the plane, I think you mean distance of the straight line connecting $\alpha(x)$ and $\alpha(y)$. Certainly that’s what your distance formula $|\alpha(x)-\alpha(y)|$ represents. But then you are treating geodesics in Euclidean space as straight lines. Then we’re back to assuming Euclidean geodesics are straight lines to prove Euclidean geodesics are straight lines. Btw the definition of geodesics given in the book doesn’t mention the plane between two points: “Definition: A geodesic arc in a metric space X is a distance-preserving function α: [a, b] → X, with a < b in R”

Comment: In fairness, and upon reflection, this definition of geodesics is sufficient to support your proof that $|\beta(s)|=s$. My error was in thinking of the distance between $\alpha(a+s)$ and $\alpha(a)$ as the distance along some curve, defined by $\alpha$. However, the distance I should have been thinking about was the standard Euclidean distance between these two points.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\beta(s) = \alpha(a + s) - x$, $|\beta(s)| = |\alpha(a + s) - x|$. This second expression is the distance between $\alpha(a) = x$ and $\alpha(a + s)$, and as $\alpha$ is a geodesic this is simply $s$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I’m not quite sure this resolves my concern tbh. So, $\beta(s)$ is the vector between $\alpha(a)$ and $\alpha(a+s)$, and so of course $|\alpha(a+s) - \alpha(a)|$ is the length of vector $\beta(s)$. To claim that this vector has length $s$, which is the length of the geodesic curve, is to imply the geodesic curve is a straight line. Which is what appears to be the objective of the proof! Obviously it doesn’t make sense to assume what’s trying to be proved. This is the source of my confusion.